# MySQL query for getting default record if specific record is not found

Tags: mysql, default-value

I would like to have a table able to store team specific values, if no record found, the default record will be returned.

TableName: ***Products***

```
ProdID  ProdName    Team
1       AAA         <NULL>
1       AAA_T1      T1
2       BBB         <NULL>
3       CCC         <NULL>
3       CCC_T1      T1
3       CCC_T2      T2
4       DDD         <NULL>
4       DDD_T3      T3
```

For the query, Team will need to pass in, all Products will be returned.

Team T1

```
ProdID  ProdName
1       AAA_T1
2       BBB
3       CCC_T1
4       DDD
```

Team T2

```
ProdID  ProdName
1       AAA
2       BBB
3       CCC_T2
4       DDD
```

Team T3

```
ProdID  ProdName
1       AAA
2       BBB
3       CCC
4       DDD_T3
```

How do I achieve this? Do I need to change the table structure?

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` of the table with itself.

Comment: Isn't what is given in your examples is just the result of `select ProdID, ProdName from Products where Team = :team or Team is null`?

Comment: @MikhailAntonov That will return BOTH the team-specific and default. It should only return the default when there's no team-specific row.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for your quick reply.
@MikhailAntonov `select p.prodid, IFNULL(t.prodname,p.prodname) from products p
left join (select prodid, prodname from products where team='T2') t on t.prodid=p.prodid 
where p.team is null` works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct p.prodname
from products p
where p.team = 'T1'
or (
  p.team is null 
  and not exists (
    select 1 from products
    where prodid = p.prodid and team = 'T1'
  )
)
```

You may remove `distinct` if there are no duplicates.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9583f383aff27d4e0b6a0a49377c4bc7).
Or with conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when team = 'T1' or team is null then prodname end) prodname
from products
group by prodid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=81921501bc44c0152912765434f56182).
Results:

```
> | prodname |
> | :------- |
> | AAA_T1   |
> | BBB      |
> | CCC_T1   |
> | DDD      |
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas for your quick reply and the demos. It works well.<br/>
Can you explain more on the having clause `having count(case when team = 'T1' or team is null then 'T1' end) > 0` using the conditional aggregation? I've tried to remove it and still works.<br/>In terms of performance, which one will you suggest if I have around 10,000 products and 5 teams?

Comment: No need for the having clause. I used it while I was trying different things with more data than your sample data in the demo and left it there. I will edit. But try first the 1st query. Sometimes EXISTS and NOT EXISTS performs better than aggregation.